# ipconfig: merge two batch files (.bat) into one

Tags: batch-file, cmd, internet-connection, tweak, ipconfig

I have two .bat files in use to toggle my Internet connection:

1) "ipconfig /release" (to switch off)

2) "ipconfig /renew" (to switch on)

Could somebody please rewrite it, so I can use ONE single file instead of two?

Specifically:

- one click - switch off;
- another one (no delay, any time, same file) - switch on;
- and so on, and so on (just clicking, without any other actions required).

Comment: Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works!

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

This uses a toggle file in the batch file directory to implement the behaviour.

```
pushd
if exist __toggle__.txt (
    del __toggle__.txt
    ipconfig /renew
) else (
    echo. > __toggle__.txt
    ipconfig /release
)
```